# 忍耐 vs 忍受 usage/difference

Tags: meaning, word-choice, usage, difference

Based on the dictionary, 忍耐 = endure, bear with, restraint oneself while 忍受 = bear, endure. But when I look at sample sentences, the usage of both words sort of overlap each other. So how do I use each word? Is there any distinguishing usage between the word? Oh BTW, this is just my guess but I sort of did notice a slight difference which is 忍受 seems to mean bear/endure a situation while 忍耐 seems to mean exercise patience/put up with someone or something.

Comment: I'd prefer 忍受 means suffer.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question here http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?3,114539,114551#msg-114551

- [忍耐](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5153/)- (n) patience; forbearance
- [忍耐](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5153/)- (v) exercise patience; restrain oneself
- [忍受](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5151/)- (v) to endure; to bear

Let's try put the terms into sentences

> 我未預備好，你要忍耐一吓。- I am not ready yet,  you have to be patient.
>
> 我未預備好，你要忍受一吓。- I am not ready yet, you have to endure it. (*Doesn't seem as suitable as be patient in this sentence.)*

~

> 我無法'忍受'這種痛苦！- I can't 'endure' this kind of pain.; I can't 'bear' this kind of pain. (*it seem like 忍受 translate to 'endure' or 'bear' is correct.)*
>
> 我無法'忍耐'這種痛苦！ - I can't 'be patient with' this kind of pain (*This sentence doesn't make much sense*)

More examples:

> 忍耐是有限度的。 (Patience has a limit)
>
> 忍受痛苦是有限度的 (Enduring pain has a limit)

Answer (score 0):

according to OP's earlier comments  "the dictionary" seems to refer to Pleco dictionary. Some users would like to suggest again consulting online dictionaries, like bkrs, iciba, Linguee, esp.noting large number of usage examples showing collocation.The following may provide additional info.

＂汉语同义词词典＂**忍耐／忍受／容忍** ［同］动词。表示承受住。

［异］［**忍耐**］着重于把痛苦的感觉或某种感情、情绪抑制住，不使表现出来。例：（１）他们勇敢、勤劳，能吃苦，能忍耐。巴金＜我们会见了彭德怀司令员＞）（２）他凭着超人的意志，忍耐最大的痛苦。（臧克家＜陈毅同志与诗＞（ed.陈毅同志喜欢写诗）（３）我为什么偏不忍耐几天，要这么急急地告诉她真话的呢？（鲁迅＜伤逝＞）

［**忍受**］着重于把痛苦、困难、不幸的遭遇或不良的待遇等勉强承受下来。语意比＂忍耐＂重。常说＂难以忍受＂。例（１）人们的践踏和狂风暴雨我都须忍受。（冰心＜分＞）（２）你要知道，我宁肯忍受痛苦，也不愿受人奴役。（刘白羽＜昆仑礼赞＞）（３）光说她这种居高临下的态度，已经叫何守礼难以忍受。（欧阳山＜圣地＞）

［**容忍**］着重于宽容、承受。对象多是缺点、错误，痛苦的、不合理的、不能接受的事情。多用于否定形式。常说＂不能容忍＂。例（１）他的错误言行使人不能容忍。（张洁＜沉重的翅膀＞）（２）这对于已经接受了现代科学文化熏陶和思想洗礼的鲁迅来说，他不能容忍这门荒唐的婚事。（王欣＜鲁迅的＂悲喜＂婚姻＞）（３）据说萧邦最不喜欢贝多芬，简直不能容忍他的音乐。＜宗璞，红豆＞）

also note above use of result complement 住 after 忍受 （see 
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%BF%8D%E5%8F%97%E4%BD%8F for 忍受 with negative potential complement 忍受不住／了.)

Answer (score 0):

耐：undergoing a long time of uncomfortable condition

受：suffering mistortures

so sometime after "忍耐"， you be may be more powerful in the future，stronger，etc.

"忍受" stresses more the bad feeling in process of enduration